# Can I sell shares for an app I made?

Tags: business, shareholders

Is this possible? I dont mean sell shares of a company that makes apps but shares of an app itself without a company.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can create a company that owns the app and sell shares in that company.

Also, depending on your situation, you might also consider a simple revenue sharing agreement instead of a corporation. This is revenue (top line, before expenses) not equity (like shares would be). Shareholders are never entitled to dividends in a corporation. Dividends have to be voted and approved by the board of directors.